# Dynamic method operator BETWEEN, open or closed interval?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm developing a project which has to generate a lot of reports. Most of them use date intervals for filtering. Let's say:

```
//this is the way I'm using to construct dates from params
def beginDate = new Date().parse("yyyy-MM-dd",""+params.beginDate_year+"-"+params.beginDate_month+"-"+params.beginDate_day)
def endDate = new Date().parse("yyyy-MM-dd",""+params.endDate_year+"-"+params.endDate_month+"-"+params.endDate_day)
//filtering
def results = MyObject.findAllByPurchaseDateBetween(beginDate, endDate)
```

When I want to retrieve info between 2014/04/01 and 2014/04/24, the dynamic method retrieves results (apparently) between 2014/04/02 and 2014/04/23.

So, does the BETWEEN  operator define a [closed](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClosedInterval.html) or an [open](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OpenInterval.html) interval?

Or, what I'm doing wrong?

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried just using the begin and end date parameters? Assuming you are using a datePicker, and assuming you are on Grails 2.3.x, the date object is automatically bound in the controller. So `def beginDate = params.beginDate` is a valid statement. I'm not positive this will fix your issue, but it will certainly clean up your code a bit.

Comment: Hi @rmlan. I'm using grails-2.2.3. I'm not sure if this version is capable to handle `def beginDate = params.beginDate`. But I'm going to use it in the future for sure. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: @ManuelCalles it would have taken you less time to test this than to post a question about it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it behaves the same as `BETWEEN` in a SQL query (which it surely must), it defines an open interval.